# Targets of 0.1/0.9 instead of 0/1 in neural networks and other classification algorithms

Tags: logistic, neural-networks, train

[Rumelhart, Hinton and Williams (PDF)](http://psych.stanford.edu/~jlm/papers/PDP/Volume%201/Chap8_PDP86.pdf) wrote in 1986 in the context of training a neural network (page 12):

> One other feature of this activation function should be noted. The
>   system can not actually reach its extreme values of 1 or 0 without
>   infinitely large weights. Therefore, in a practical learning situation
>   in which the desired outputs are binary {0, 1}, the system can never
>   actually achieve these values. **Therefore, we typically use the values
>   of 0.1 and 0.9 as the targets, even though we will talk as if values
>   of {0, 1} are sought.**

I haven't seen this advice in any more recent paper, nor in any piece of code implementing a neural network. My questions:

1. Is this advice still valid, or was it disproved as ineffective at some point?
2. Was this advice used (historically) in other algorithms, e.g. logistic regression?

Comment: Where is it exactly? Could you point it with pages of the paper? If the output is sigmoid, they don't reach to either 0 or 1 as long as there is no under or over-flow. But it is not necessary to set targets to another value for it, as test time network assign the label to the maximum (or > 0.5) output unit.

Comment: @yasin.yazici: page 12, or "329" from the scan, penultimate paragraph. (The question initially mentioned page 9, I have no idea why I wrote it so). I don't understand your remark; could you explain?

Comment: This sounds like strange advice.  Why is it necessary for predictions to exactly equal observed values?  Even if you do this recoding you'll almost never achieve that anyways using the sigmoid function.

Comment: @dsaxton the gradient descent steps depend on the derivative of the activation function.  If you use a logistic activation function then the derivative is numerically zero before you get to 1 or 0.  As a result the optimisation can never absolutely converge.  I wouldn't use the modified targets for that reason, but the way it is used by Platt is much more reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Coding the targets as $\{0.1, 0.9\}$ is an example of label smoothing. It's one of the tricks highlighted in [this review](https://myrtle.ai/how-to-train-your-resnet-8-bag-of-tricks/) and it appears to originate in "[Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567)" by Christian Szegedy et al. as a certain kind of regularization. It's used as a regularization strategy to discourage a neural network from giving over-confident predictions in the outcome, because the predicted probabilities cannot be improved by becoming arbitrarily close to 1 for the true class; instead, the lowest loss value occurs at 0.9 for the true class.

The standard approach is to not use label smoothing.  When we estimate a logistic regression (a 0-hidden layer neural network with sigmoid activations on the last layer), we never do this; the problem is left "as is" for Newton's Method to solve. Provided that the usual conditions are satisfied (design matrix is full-rank, perfect separation is not present), we have no problem estimating the regression coefficients. Likewise, neural networks trained on binary problems proceed in the same way! Nonlinearities and multiple layers make the optimization more challenging, but the core concept is the same.

However, neural networks are more flexible models, and are able to find more complex relationships compared to logistic regression. This means that they are also more prone to giving uncalibrated outcomes (the predicted probabilities do not strongly correspond to the true probabilities), a trend that is remarked upon in  "[Your classifier is secretly an energy-based model, and you should treat it like one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.03263.pdf)" by Will Grathwohl, et al. (which also has citations to  other papers making similar observaitons).

Comment: I think it may also be partly due to numerical issues evaluating the derivative of the output layer activation function - most modern implementations deal with it in a less heuristic manner.  Another trick from the old days was to add an offset to the derivative so progress could still be made if the neuron were (numerically) saturated.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I know that there can be numerical issues if the output & loss are computed naïvely (round-tripping $\exp$ and $\log$ in softmax and cross-entropy loss) but that's easily addressed by combining the operations and simplifying the algebra. Is there a second kind of numerical issue that is not solved by simplifying the algebra?

Comment: The most common trick is to bound the net activation for the neuron.  This is well known now, but I'm not sure it was well known outside statistics back in the day.  My first MLP implementation back in the very early 90s didn't have it :-(

Comment: That certainly explains the value that the authors of OP's paper (published 1986) find. I think that the application in the Szegedy et al. paper (published 2015) find is slightly different, and is essentially a trick to prevent the network from making over-confident prediction; certainly, numerical methods to avoid over/underflow would be well-known by that time. (Additionally, Szegedy et al. use a dramatically different magnitude of the smoothing.)

Comment: Yes, Platt uses it for a similar (good) reason to get probabilities from SVM (which is not such a good idea).  The original motivation for it was not so good!

Comment: Yeah, Platt scaling was such a strange development. In the years since then, there's been a lot more cross-pollination and collaboration between the statistical and machine learning communities, but Platt scaling almost feels like the last major publication that exemplifies the extent to which statistics and machine learning were two ships passing in the night. (But clearly both communities have a lot to offer each other, and collaboration essential!)

Comment: I much prefer kernel logistic regression for the sort of task where a hybrid of the SVM and statistics would be useful!  ML done right really is computational statistics.  A lot of it isn't done right though.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the reasons they suggested this approach was that the magnitudes of the gradient descent steps in back-propagation are proportional to the derivative of the activation function. If you use a logistic activation function then the derivative is numerically zero before the output reaches 1 or 0.  As a result the optimization can never absolutely converge as the loss function has a very long trough in weight-space with a very shallow slope along the bottom.  Using these modified targets backpropagation is able to converge to a more definite minimum.  I used this technique a bit back in the very early 90s‡, and it doesn't really give much of a benefit in practice, especially if the modification to the targets is as large as that!

A more recent usage of this trick can be found in [Platt Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platt_scaling), which is used to get estimates of the probability of class membership from support vector machines†.  In Platt Scaling, a logistic regression model is fitted to the (leave-one-out) scores outputted by the SVM, but with modified targets (as @Sycorax explains +1) as a regularisation method to avoid over-fitting.  However Platt adopts a much less heuristic (and less drastic) approach, and sets the targets to be

$y_+ = \frac{N_+ + 1}{N + 2} \qquad \mathrm{and} \qquad  y_- = \frac{N_- + 1}{N + 2}$

which is effectively a Bayesian regularisation based on the Laplace correction.

† **Really** - don't do this, if you want probabilities (and for most practical applications, you will), use a proper probabilistic classifier, such as kernel logistic regression or Gaussian process classifiers (if you like to be Bayesian).

‡ The PDP books were where I first learned about neural networks! (my copy is from 1989 ;o)